# Any way to get lightning-datatable to not render borders?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, lightning-datatable

In [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#With-no-borders) there is the class `slds-table_bordered` that results in table borders and [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/specification) emits that class by default.

I don't see any way to stop that to have a borderless table that is helpful e.g. when multiple tables are presented in one page inside accordions that already generate horizontal lines. Is there a way to have a borderless table using this component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So AFAIK today, the answer is **no**.